# Approximating Hessian matrix (or its inverse) without gradient information

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, hessian-matrix

I have access to a black-box function, $f(\mathbf{x})$, with $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a way to efficiently approximate the Hessian matrix at a point, $\mathbf{x_0}$, without access to the gradient information?

I know the [BFGS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) approximates the inverse of Hessian matrix by updating the matrix in each iteration with new gradient information. However, if the gradient information is unavailable, I haven't seen any algorithm that approximate the Hessian matrix.

Comment: the old finite differences don't work?

Comment: It works fine, it is just the finite differences requires $O(n^2)$ evaluations per points, which is too slow in my case.

Comment: How about a random sampling around some small neighbourhood $\bf x_0 + r_\epsilon$ and fitting a 2nd degree polynomial level set to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use finite-difference Quasi-Newton (e.g., BFGS).  Finite differences  (O(n) per point) are used to evaluate the gradient, and Quasi-Newton update is used to approximate the Hessian (or its inverse).

This as opposed to O(n^2) per point to evaluate the Hessian by finite differences of gradients calculated by finite differences.

Comment: Thank you! It is quite obvious apparently, but I oversaw it. Thanks!

Comment: I did not invent this. It has been widely used for decades, even though it is not mentioned that much in books.